# How do you prove that $\frac{10^{n}-1}{10^{n}-2}=1+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^{i}\times10^{-n(i+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I was just wondering around and I've noticed that $\frac{9\ldots9}{9\ldots8}$ ratio, lets say $\frac{99}{98}$ is beautiful: $1.010204081632$. Basically, this is powers of two separated by as many zeros as you have nines in denominator. I'm not that good in math to understand the underlying principle, I'm just curious why this happens and what powers of twos has to do with $\frac{99}{98}$.

Comment: While it's not exactly a mystery for the old pros, this is indeed a beautiful little pattern you've discovered. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sum is a geometric series: $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^i \times 10^{-n(i+1)} = 10^{-n} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left( \frac{2}{10^n}\right)^i = 10^{-n} \times \frac{1}{1 - 2 \times 10^{-n}} = \frac{1}{10^n - 2}$$

You are done once you observe that $$\frac{10^n-1}{10^n -2 } = \frac{10^n-2}{10^n -2 } + \frac{1}{10^n -2 } = 1 +  \frac{1}{10^n -2 }$$